# How to get the same class as the class of 'this'?

Tags: jquery

How can I get the audio element with the same class as the class of the clicked element (img)? It's important to notice that the audio element is not a .parent, .child, .sibling or .closest, it is far away in the code from the clicked element but it has the same class.
I don't want to state the class in the code, cause it is thought to be universal for many clickable objects.

$(this).click(function(){
var player = $("audio element with the same class as the class of "this" ")[0].play();

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 different ways:

1. to use specify audio el selector in img tag data-attribute. Very flexible as you can use ID, className, everything...
2. your solution with the same class. But the logic is very similar for both of them.

In your case you need to extract img element classes.
e.g.
`const imgClasses = jQuery(this).attr('class')`
Now you can create selector for the audio
`const selector = 'audio.' + imgClasses.split(' ').join('.')`
Or you can use replace, or use not all classes but the only specific one
When you have selector you can find audio
`const player$ = jQuery(selector);`
...
...
...

Comment: Thank you! I scripted something like this, but it seems not to work:

$(document).ready(function(){
$(this).click(function(){
const imgClasses = jQuery(this).attr('class');
const selector = 'audio.' + imgClasses.split(' ').join('.');
const player$ = 
$(selector)[0].play();
$(selector).prop('muted', false);
});
});

Comment: okay, now I know - I just needed to make it more specified. Instead "this" it should be img. Thank you!